# Where could I file a list of Meego Hamattan built in UIs?

Tags: qt, qml, meego, meego-harmattan

For example a Button component has a default background property of:
"image://theme/meegotouch-button"+__invertedString+"-background"+(position?"-"+position:"

or

A ToolIcon's platformIconId could have a value of "toolbar-view-menu" and automatically it is the equal sign like icon in the tool bar.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/MeeGo_Harmattan_QML_ToolIcon_Element_and_Various_icons